# Proper usage of ARMv6 equates: .equ .reg .set

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, binutils, armv6

Using the GNU Assembler Manual, v2.19.51, I was not able to find a definitive difference between these types of equates:

- **.equ**
- **.reg**
- **.set**

Does anyone know the difference and proper usage?

Answer (score 2):

`.equ` and `.set` are documented to be the same. I was not able to find any mention of `.reg`, where did you see that? There is however a `.req` which defines register aliases, as opposed to the other two which define symbols.

Comment: Interestingly, I just came across this link that gave a definitive definition of the equates.
http://bel.gsi.de/scripts/gnu-arm-assy-quick-ref.pdf
They indicates that .equ is a directive that sets the value of a symbol while, .set sets the value of a variable and .req (my mistaken typo of .reg in original note) defines the name of a register.

Comment: The definite is the [GAS manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/as/index.html). And [that says `.equ` and `.set` are the same](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/as/Equ.html) and `.reg` is for registers, as I have written in the answer. There is no such thing as a variable anyway.